# Block people from returning to site?

Tags: javascript, timeout, client-side

I'm tasked with coming up with a way to determine if a person has reached our site via using their back button (meaning they left our site and came back) and log them out if so.

I've come up with some options, but am wondering what other options I may be missing.

FYI, we do have a session state, so server-side we're covered for long absences, but they want an additional check on the client side.

option 1: set a cooking via onunload that expires in x seconds. On each page of our site, I check for said cookie. If it exists, I assume they came from another page on our site and do nothing. If it's not there, I assume they have been gone from our site more more than x seconds and redirect out. Con: Blackberry devices running OS5 don't support onunload.

option 2: same as #1 but instead of setting cookie onunload, we set it on every click of every link that goes to another page on our site. con: messy

option 3: <strike>check browser history on every load of every page of our site. If the previous URL is not one of ours, we log them out. Cons: browser support?</strike> It looks like previous/next history objects are now blocked in modern browsers due to security.

Option 4: Via JS, every x seconds, check for a cookie. If it's there, reset it to expire in x seconds. If it's not there, assume they've returned from somewhere else. Con: Not sure if the JS cookies would be set while that page may be in the background (app switching on an iPhone, or using a different tab in a desktop browser).

Any other options I should consider? Is there a 'proper' way to handle this? Is this just grasping at straws trying to prevent normal browser behavior?

Comment: I'm interested in some other exploration on this.  I have seen some interesting Javascript done with cookies and others with AJAX session checks.

Comment: Option 5: Give up. Seriously though, option 1 and 2 are flawed for obvious reasons (the intermittent nature of the internet for one), option 3 is blown out of the water when considering the de facto standard is tabbed-browsing now, and option 4, well, that's just plain silly. Anything else pretty much _is_ grasping at straws, beating a dead horse - whatever the euphemism, they all spell trouble in such touchy cases.

Comment: I should give more context. This is mainly for mobile devices. As such, we're not going the AJAX route due to network lag. The tabbed browsing is an issue, though, in things like mobile safari.

Comment: Seems kind of stupid to me to log someone out just because they are coming back to your site.

Comment: @stingy: yep, it is. The problem is corporate security people still don't seem to really understand how the web and web browsers actually work.

Answer (score 1):

You could keep the current page name/action/identifier in a session variable, then use a javascript onChange/load/keyup/keydown to request the current state of the user from the server.  If it does not match, redirect or otherwise block them from viewing the current page.

This is a method that I've used, but it has it's downsides.... for example, onload doesn't always seem to work when the user uses the back button.  OnChange, etc on certain form fields definitely works.  Timers are pretty straightforward, as well, but a quick user can get input through the page regardless.

Comment: We're trying to avoid hitting the server to compare to session state. So, yea, we're kind of trying to do the impossible. ;)

Comment: @DA - you are already kind of screwing over the server by using session anyways, so whats the big deal with adding one more check?

Comment: It's less the server and more the network lag we'd be getting on some of our mobile devices/networks.

Answer (score 0):

It's not that complicated... Use javascript history object

history.next gives you the complete url of the page in the forward button. A simple regex can tell if it's from your domain or not.

I just don't know if it's supported by all browsers

Comment: looks like modern browsers are blocking access to the next/previous history objects in the browser, which makes perfect sense from a security POV. So, crossing that one off the options list.